# How get Url of an action within an ApiController which is in a area?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I have an area with the name **admin**, and i have an `ApiController` in this area by the name **ProductPicture**, in this controller i have action by the name **AddProductPicture**, i want call this action from a view (which is in the same area),
so i write

```
  $upload.upload({
                url:'/Admin/api/ProductPicture/AddProductPicture',
                fields:$routeParams.ProductId,
                file: file
            })
```

for access to it, but it does not work, and console give me error 404, what is the problem?

EDIT : i added this code to `WebApiConfig` in `App_Start` :

```
  public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "API Area",
        routeTemplate: "Admin/api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        )
    }
```

and the URL in network tab :`http://localhost:3471/Admin/api/ProductPicture/AddProductPicture`
but it does not work!!

Comment: 404 is a server path problem or error response created at server based on what was sent. No way for us to know why based on a javascript snippet.

Comment: @charlietfl i know, this error caused due to the path that i defined is not correct, i want to know how i can correct this

Answer (score 0):

You need to register a route for Admin Area.

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        ...

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        // ***** This is what you need *****
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "AdminDefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "Admin/api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I added this before, but it does not work. i edit my question

Comment: Does regular MVC controller work inside Admin area? Btw, you cannot view in browser if AddProductPicture requires HttpPost method; you need to use **fiddler** or **PostMan**.

Comment: Does WebApi controller work if you place it inside default **~/Controllers** folder?

Comment: I create an api in ~/Controller , and changed the url to :   url: '/api/ProductPicture/AddProductPicture',   But it gave me 404 error!! what happend!!

Answer (score 0):

Can you send the code for the ApiController and the your routing config? You can also open the developer tools in your browser, check the Network tab and see what path is being actually being called.